# Raspberry Pi Camera v2 not detected for Octopi on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, camera, raspicam, picamera

I've searched all over the internet for a solution to my problem, but it seems like every route comes up short for me. Again, I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 with a Pi Cam v2, and using PuTTy as my SSH.
Here is a list of my problems and attempted solutions where applicable:

1. in Octopi, webcam stream does not load (the rest of Octopi functions correctly)

   a) if using the Octopi(stable) download, I get a "The webcam server is currently not running" message when I click for more info

   b) if using OctoPi(new camera stack), I get a similar message, but not about connecting
   to the server(sorry I cannot remember the exact message, it was the first thing I
   tried so it is not currently on this Pi).

   c) I checked my CSI cable, and it is in the "camera" port, not the "display" port. I also
   made sure the cable connectors in the raspberry pi and the camera are facing the correct way, and that they are fully seated in their ports on the Pi and camera respectively
2. in SSH, vcgencmd get_camera returns "supported=1, detected=0"

   a) I have tried enabling i2C and Camera in the config interface settings, but no cigar

   b) I have tried adjusting the memory allocation in the config settings as well, from 128
   to 512 and 256, but the error persists
3. libcamera-hello --list-cameras returns "No available cameras!", and libcamera-hello
   returns an error message saying it cannot find a camera either

   a) I also tried sudo apt update and sudo apt full-upgrade.

Am I totally out of options? Or am I stupid and missed something? I don't want to believe the hardware is the problem anywhere, but I'm starting to lose optimism and patience. Any feedback or calrifying questions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you're probably better off asking this on the octoprint forum https://community.octoprint.org/

Comment: Have you tried using the camera without octopi?  You have given no evidence that the camera has ever worked,

Comment: @joan My brother lent me his old Pi 3 (same model) and it doesn't seem to detect it on that one either. I presume that means the camera is bad?

Comment: @user156889 Certainly suggestive.  Are you sure the flat cable is the right way around?

Comment: @joan Yes. The blue is facing the ports, and in the camera, the blue is on the backside. I also tried a different ribbon cable and got the same results